# sql COUNT question

Tags: sql, count

How can I modify this query to return results that exclude all records that have a duplicate DocNum?

```
SELECT IdEntry, DocNum, CardCode, QUOTENAME(CardName,'"'), 
Convert(Decimal(10,2),PayAmount), Convert(Decimal(10,2),InvPayAmnt), 
CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), T5.PmntDate,101), NumAtCard, PymMeth, ObjType
FROM DELAWARE.dbo.PWZ3
INNER JOIN OPWZ T5 ON T5.IdNumber = IdEntry
WHERE T5.PmntDate = '3/10/2011' 
AND T5.Canceled = 'N' 
AND Checked = 'Y'
```

Comment: Can you help us with a schema? if there's a primary key, a self join makes it easy (parent.docNum = child.docNum and parent.idEntry <> child.idEntry)

Comment: IdEntry is primary key of PWZ3 and IdNumber is Primary key of OPWZ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
WITH
    dups (DocNum)
    AS (
        SELECT DocNum
        FROM DELAWARE.dbo.PWZ3
        GROUP BY DocNum
        HAVING COUNT(1) > 1
    )
SELECT PWZ3.IdEntry, PWZ3.DocNum, PWZ3.CardCode, QUOTENAME(CardName,'"'), 
Convert(Decimal(10,2),PayAmount), Convert(Decimal(10,2),InvPayAmnt), 
CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), T5.PmntDate,101), NumAtCard, PymMeth, ObjType
FROM DELAWARE.dbo.PWZ3 PWZ3
INNER JOIN OPWZ T5 ON T5.IdNumber = PWZ3.IdEntry
LEFT JOIN Dups ON DUPS.DocNum = PWZ3.DocNum
WHERE T5.PmntDate = '3/10/2011' 
AND T5.Canceled = 'N' 
AND Checked = 'Y'
AND Dups.DocNum is null
```

(I might not have all the column aliases right)

Comment: Sure. The WITH statement creates a temporary table for the duration of the query - that query contains all the duplicate docnums. Then the left join + the is null condition restricts the query to return rows where there is no entry in the table of duplicates.

Comment: I would rather select those `HAVING COUNT(*) = 1` and inner joined against that list. But the question is, should it be so? I mean, does the question imply that `docNum`s that are duplicated should be omitted from the result set altogether? Because initially I thought the query should simply have distinct `docNum`s, i.e. even if some values are duplicated, one value from every group of duplicated values should be selected anyway.

Comment: For this specific situation, I would like to omit all duplicates. Thanks guys!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understood all the query, but doesn't a simple

```
 SELECT ... GROUP BY docNum
```

suffice?

Comment: This doesn't work since I am selecting more then one column which I do not want to group.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT IdEntry, DocNum, CardCode, QUOTENAME(CardName,'"'), 
Convert(Decimal(10,2),PayAmount), Convert(Decimal(10,2),InvPayAmnt), 
CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), T5.PmntDate,101), NumAtCard, PymMeth, ObjType

FROM DELAWARE.dbo.PWZ3
INNER JOIN OPWZ T5 ON T5.IdNumber = IdEntry

JOIN (SELECT min(IdEntry) as minIdEntry from DELAWARE.dbo.PWZ3 group by DocNum) tmp on DELAWARE.dbo.PWZ3.IdEntry = minIdEntry

WHERE T5.PmntDate = '3/10/2011' 
AND T5.Canceled = 'N' 
AND Checked = 'Y'
```

Comment: Indent everything 4 spaces to allow syntax highlighting.